# how can I delay a signal in simulink?

Tags: matlab, simulink

my problem is very simple,yet I didn't find a solution online.

let's say I have a sin block, and my singal is sin(5t).

How can I start the signal after 5 seconds? so that it's 0 for the first 5 seconds and sin(5t) after those.

Comment: What does google tell you, if you type "delay a signal in simulink"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [transport delay block](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/simulink/slref/transportdelay.html?refresh=true).

It just delays a signal a given amount of time.

Comment: thank you... do you know how to ''shut down'' the signal after some seconds? I'd like to let my sin be different from zero for a couple of seconds then return to zero. thanks in advance

Comment: @user3149593 you can always use a switch and a time block.